# xades4j validation error: Reference '' cannot be validated

Tags: java, validation, reference, xades4j

I get an error like this when I try to validate a XADES file:

```
xades4j.verification.ReferenceValueException: Reference '' cannot be validated
at deployment.mora.war//xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.doCoreVerification(XadesVerifierImpl.java:354)
at deployment.mora.war//xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:214)
```

The code to verify is this:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(SIGNED)));
    DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(doc.getDocumentElement());

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Signature");

    FileSystemDirectoryCertStore certStore = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore(CERT_FOLDER);
    KeyStore ks;
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(CERT_FOLDER + KEY_STORE)) {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        ks.load(fis, PASS.toCharArray());
    }

    CertificateValidationProvider provider = PKIXCertificateValidationProvider.builder(ks)
                .checkRevocation(false)
                .intermediateCertStores(certStore.getStore())
                .build();
    XadesVerificationProfile profile = new XadesVerificationProfile(provider);
    org.w3c.dom.Element sigElem = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nl.item(0);
    XAdESVerificationResult r = profile.newVerifier().verify(sigElem, null);
```

The signature element inside the XADES is like that:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />

<ds:Reference Id="Reference-bce06403-5236-41d2-876e-fa045b90290d" URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<ds:DigestValue>vj9jpZh17pKA28p7a34YsTC7rrwof55klvGjnf0bPPM=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>

<ds:Reference Id="ReferenceKeyInfo" URI="#KeyInfoId-Signature-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<ds:DigestValue>GDh/QzYxs0rqhpR0pSmaJrsevT+OMoj/exTN0BvzlRw=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>

<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#SignedProperties-Signature-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<ds:DigestValue>5q0IptSTJjVcURg4dQrEIKSBVHjP7sSmN5hwKzq2VZs=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>

</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="SignatureValue-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">N2iKgDKSy...==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyInfoId-Signature-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIII8D...</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
<ds:KeyValue>
<ds:RSAKeyValue>
<ds:Modulus>wgcwrorO+vOgKWGMzLCega0a/oNMdSHMTxmO6C7z7ISfU80ddnlODmutRl5OLaHLDgaRVCJ9KmNPpW8uW/c8KOvnCt6JMOyUb1yBnLJgl5YGgJSelLXmZrUNp3daRFqE46C1o53LS93ljQ63vWDlYQIdqaSBCMKYNpqBX0PBPHft8v8Od0NvuCEnRlWhOYXITo/Lu7p3mCuRNYiJ8MZHPf4faoalhMA5y9sFZHTqtr1XrDoM3D5UrTPbubVkKMFK1xQyDyb9Vj7m1NSwv63lgDpG2ouSK2t6ixzxgf/GTkN3el2Nx+6QhNro92IkicE3aRew9P756V5l3063PHyMzQ==</ds:Modulus>
<ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
</ds:RSAKeyValue>
</ds:KeyValue>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object Id="XadesObjectId-642b3de2-fb1a-424e-87a6-59be13fadf1f">
<xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="QualifyingProperties-a522752d-2de4-4f5a-9d30-830370962953" Target="#Signature-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">
<xades:SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties-Signature-a0357d3c-02ff-4a71-888c-aab6fc2a8b1e">
<xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SigningTime>2022-02-08T10:04:05+01:00</xades:SigningTime>
<xades:SigningCertificate>
<xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<ds:DigestValue>gb86Dv+uNj+Dsup33d2FvOx7f22G/jX7UstM7uH8i4c=</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
<xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=AC Representación, OU=CERES, O=FNMT-RCM, C=ES</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>81878359483328253772408023375514979749</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
</xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
<xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-bce06403-5236-41d2-876e-fa045b90290d">
<xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType>
<xades:Encoding>UTF-8</xades:Encoding>
</xades:DataObjectFormat>
</xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
</xades:SignedProperties>
</xades:QualifyingProperties>
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

The XADES is not generated using xades4j, but the file "passes" the validation of several online testers (https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml#generatedCode, https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation, https://validator.fina.hr/eSigWebApp-web/#validate), so I suppose that the xades4j validation I perform is stronger in some way...

How should I configure the CertificateValidationProvider in order to pass the validation? I mean that I only want to check the integrity of the XADES file (ensure that the content has not been altered, basically check the digests and the signature)

Comment: At first glance, the code seems correct. The error you're getting is related to the digest value of the Reference, so not related to certificate validation. 
Could it be some problem when reading the file (e.g. encoding or so) that would make the contents look different?

Comment: Another time, you are correct... putting new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(SIGNED), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) instead of  FileReader(SIGNED), validation runs Ok! Thanks another time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you provide to the validator only the ds:Signature element:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Signature");
```

While you should provide the complete XML document, as the signature covers the enveloping content, see the first reference URI:

```
<ds:Reference Id="Reference-bce06403-5236-41d2-876e-fa045b90290d" URI="">
```

The empty URI="" means the validator needs to dereference the whole XML node containing the current signature, and in your case it fails, as it cannot find the enveloping content. See [XMLDSig](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-ReferenceProcessingModel) for more information about the signature dereference model.